# How to trigger load event listener in useEffect everytime component rerenders?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to convert some static html/css site to react.js. In `script` tag there is this function that applies some css transition when the window loads everytime. Here's the function below:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
   document.querySelectorAll('.progress-custom-bar-fill').forEach(e => {
      e.style.width = `${e.getAttribute('fill-progress')}%`;
      })
})

        <div
          className={`progress-custom-bar-fill ${goodOrOk}`}
          fill-progress={progress}
        />
```

I tried appyling style property directly to the `div` like this:

```
         <div
          style={{ width: `${progress}%` }}
          className={`progress-custom-bar-fill ${goodOrOk}`}
          fill-progress={progress}
        />
```

It worked, but it doesn't appy css transiton

I tried useEffect, it works only first time when the window loads, but when switching between pages it doesn't work. This is what I tried:

```
useEffect(() => {
    function updateProgressBar() {
      document.querySelectorAll('.progress-custom-bar-fill').forEach((e) => {
        e.style.width = `${e.getAttribute('fill-progress')}%`;
      });
    }
    window.addEventListener('load', updateProgressBar);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('load', updateProgressBar);
  });
```

How to make useEffect to rerender on load event? Or is there any other solution for this? Thanks in advance

Comment: are you using react-router? you can add dependency to your useEffect like `useEffect(() => { /**your UI function...**/}, [location.pathname])`. This is assuming you're using [useLocation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/uselocation)

Comment: Now your useEffect hook will be called every time your components renders